# Detect when Visual Studio is test-firing the website for intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

*There's a lot of exposition here - but it's needed.*

Not sure how many people are aware of this, but, the Razor code editor in Visual Studio causes your website to be 'test-fired' up to just before the `Application_Start` event - and this is causing some annoying issues in my current project, which uses WebActivator to do a lot of the site initialisation.

***Update - On closer inspection it's not just Razor - it looks like it's Visual Studio-wide - hence the change of title***

I need to be able to detect when website code is being run by Visual Studio and not by a web server.

To demonstrate - do the following (**exactly** as written to ensure it reproduces):

- Create a new MVC 4 site, I used the Internet Application template so there were some pages there on creation.
- Add the WebActivator package from nuget
- Add a class to the App_Start folder called `RazorPageBugTest`
- Paste this code (changing the relevant namespace):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MvcApplication6.App_Start;
using System.IO;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(
  typeof(RazorPageBugTest), "Start", Order = 0)]

namespace MvcApplication6.App_Start
{
  public static class RazorPageBugTest
  {
    public static void Start()
    {
      using (var writer = File.Open(@"c:\trace.txt", FileMode.Create))
      {
        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(writer))
        {
          tw.AutoFlush = true;
          tw.WriteLine("Written at {0}", DateTime.Now);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that this code is not something that would usually work on a web server anyway - given that it's writing to drive C: (indeed this might not work on your machine if you don't run VS as administrator).

- Now build the project.
- *This next bit works best if you already have Explorer open on C:* Once that's completed, find a Razor view and open it
- Wait for all the C#/VB bits to be highlighted
- Take a look at drive C - oh look, there's a file called 'trace.txt' and the date is within the last few seconds!

So that demonstrates the problem here - the Razor code editor is firing up an AppDomain and, effectively, shelling the website in order to get intellisense (including things like stuff in the App_Helpers folder etc).  Now it doesn't actually trigger the `Application_Start` method - but when you have WebActivator in the project as well, any of its pre-application-start methods ***are*** triggered.

In my case this is causing huge issues - high CPU usage and memory usage in `devenv.exe` (equivalent to the website having just been started) because I initialise DI containers and god-knows what else at this point, but one in particular is proving *really* annoying.

My website has a component that listens on the network for status and cache-invalidation messages from other machines in the web farm.  In QA and Live environments this listener never fails to open the port and listen - on my dev machine, however, it frequently fails - saying the port's already in use.  When I look for the process that's holding it open - it's always `devenv.exe`.

You guessed it - I start this listener in a WebActivator-initialised boot-strapping call.

So the question is - does anyone know of a way to detect that the code *isn't* being run by a 'proper' web host so I can stop it being run?  I'm particularly hopeful for this as it'll also mean that my Visual Studio and Razor editing experience will become a damn-site faster as a result!

As a bonus, any fix could legitimately be sent to David Ebbo - author of WebActivator - so he can stick it earlier in his stack to prevent the problem completely!

**Update**

I have just added [an issue to the WebActivator page on GitHub](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator/issues/8) to see if David Ebbo can push either my fix, or a better one, down into the WebActivator component.

Comment: Did you try reporting this to Visual Studio team?

Comment: Well it's by design - in order to get intellisense on your pages it needs to spin up the runtime environment - so I doubt there's anything they'd do about it.  It's perhaps more a question for David Ebbo - the author of WebActivator

Comment: I have just done this very thing in fact: [WebActivator Issue: "WebActivator is indirectly causing performance degradation in Visual Studio" on Github](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator/issues/8)

Comment: There's plenty of issues besides performance degradation, resource locking being the most obvious one. I do not think it is the WebActivator's issue though, it is a design issue. The VS should have the intellisense built in differently, not having to spin up another process and then leave it running. If it must do that, it should do it only to acquire intellisense then shut it down immediately. I think we should open a Connect issue for this, what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing your own logic to detect this, you can just use `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InClientBuildManager`, which will be true both for when VS runs that code and when it runs in aspnet_compiler.exe.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642691/avoid-aspnet-compiler-running-preapplicationstart-method/13689600#13689600) for some more details on this.

Comment: Thanks for this - am going to try using this instead of my hacky attempt :-)

Answer (score 4):

Guess what the value of `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName` will be in this case?

Answer: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host`.

So if there's a `VisualStudio` in the name of the process, you could safely scrape it.

Also check [`this article`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx) out about the hosting process.

Comment: interesting - I have got a fix (I've just implemented it before coming back to check answers here); but in my case (Visual Studio 2010) the value of `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName` is `devenv`

Comment: In fact - it's definitely *not* the hosting process because it's always devenv that grabs that network port that the website wants to use - checking the process name is still the best way I know yet, though.

Comment: marking as answer because there is no obvious better way than to check the process name -  even deep reflection on the hosting environment, looking for internal types,  or whatever won't do it as the appdomain 'looks' viable from that point of view.  its a horrible hack but it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst Darin is correct with his info about the hosting process - that only applies to VS2012 from what I can see.  Earlier versions of VS host directly inside devenv.

Since I have a nuget package stack here at work, I've put this extension method into our Web core component, which merges into the `WebActivator` namespace:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebActivator
{
  public static class HostInformation
  {
    private static readonly string[] _knownDevEnvironments = new[] { 
      "devenv",
      "microsoft.visualstudio.web.host"
    };
    private static Lazy<bool> _isDevelopmentEnvironment = new Lazy<bool>(
      () => _knownDevEnvironments.Any(
        s => s.Equals(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName,
                      StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
      ));

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the current hosting environment is a known 
    /// development environment instead of a web server or similar.
    /// 
    /// This is used to decide whether or not to actually run 
    /// pre-application-start methods which are undesirable to 
    /// run in the development environment.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsDevelopmentEnvironment
    {
      get
      {
        return _isDevelopmentEnvironment.Value;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

All of which means that in my `App_Start` startups, where conveniently `WebActivator` is already in the namespaces list - I can do this:

```
if(HostInformation.IsDevelopmentEnvironment)
  return;
```

Thus enabling all the start methods to bunk out earlier.

I hate this solution, to be honest, but by the same token there isn't really an easier way to do it.

On the plus-side my VS (both 2010 and 2012) is now very fast in presenting intellisense to me for Razor files; doesn't grow massively in memory and - more importantly - never grabs hold of that network port...